# How to change atomic vectors to run an ANOVA?

Tags: r, vector, atomic, anova

I want to conduct a two-way ANOVA using r. I have four columns: Case (1-356), ab_all (my IV), appeal (with 3 levels) and product (with 2 levels).
Unfortunately I always receive an error warning:

> "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors".

I know that I need to convert my data into a recursive object. But everything I tried failed.
Do you know how to solve the issue?

I already tried 
<- data.frame()
as.data.frame(mydata)

```
str(mainstudy_category)
'data.frame':   356 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ CASE   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ ab_all : num  5 5 5 5 4.4 3.2 4.2 2.8 3.8 5 ...
 $ appeal : Factor w/ 3 levels "emotional negative",..: 2 2 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 1 ...
 $ product: Factor w/ 2 levels "hedonic","utilitarian": 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
model_category<-lm(ab_all~product*appeal, data=mainstudy_category)
anova(model_category, type="III")
```

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

My Data:

```
structure(list(CASE = 1:6, ab_all = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 4.4, 3.2), appeal = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("emotional negative", "emotional positive", "rational"), class = "factor"), product = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("hedonic", "utilitarian"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data with `dput`?

Comment: Sure, since it's too much, maybe just the head:
> dput(head(mainstudy_category))
structure(list(CASE = 1:6, ab_all = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 4.4, 3.2), 
    appeal = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("emotional negative", 
    "emotional positive", "rational"), class = "factor"), product = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("hedonic", "utilitarian"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I am not sure about the `type=="III"` option.  but just `anova(model_category)` works.

Comment: Thank you Dave2e! I got the type III thing from a youtube tutorial. Anyway, now it works :)

Comment: Looking into this further, there is a function `Anova` from the "car" package which one can specify the type.

Comment: Thanks Dave2e for the info :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem ($ operator error even with as.data.frame). Make sure to install and load the "car" package:

```
install.packages("car", dependencies=TRUE)
library(car)
```

The anova function from "car" is written with a capital "A":

```
Anova(model_category, type="III")
```